# MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top is returning 0.0 when I'm using it with appBar. Why is that?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, emulation

When I use `MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top` without the navBar in the widget tree then it returns me the actual true value.

```
Reloaded 1 of 529 libraries in 637ms.
I/flutter (31730): 24.0
```

But when I place the appBar into the widget tree then it returns me 0.0 only.

```
Reloaded 1 of 529 libraries in 764ms.
I/flutter (31730): 0.0
```

Can someone please help that why it is happening?

Answer (score 4):

From this property's [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQueryData/padding.html):

> If you consumed this padding (e.g. by building a widget that envelops or accounts for this padding in its layout in such a way that children are no longer exposed to this padding), you should remove this padding for subsequent descendants in the widget tree by inserting a new MediaQuery widget using the MediaQuery.removePadding factory.

As the top padding is accounted for by the navBar, it is no longer exposed to widgets below it.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out now. I can collect the status bar size by calculating it before adding the navBar into the widget tree. :)

Comment: can you provide a code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I passed the `padding` value.
and I consumed the `padding.top` in my Page1.

```dart
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final padding = MediaQuery.of(context).padding;
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: IndexedStack(
          children: [
            Page1(padding),
            Page2(),
            Page3(),
            Page4(),
          ],
        ),
```